# How can the posit algorithm be used to calibrate a projector and camera

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, homogenous-transformation

I'm trying to calibrate my kinect to a projector. I've read a few papers from microsoft research on how they do this.

> four points must be correctly identified both by the depth cameras and
>   located in the projector image, after which we use the POSIT algorithm
>   [6] to find the position and orientation of the projector. This
>   process requires the focal length and center of projection of the
>   projector.

(this will give the position of the projector)

But I'm really not familiar with the posit algorithm and certainly not how it is used here. The result of the Posit algorithm is a translation vector and a rotation matrix. Now my question is how can this be used for interaction.

For example if i track a hand with the kinect i get some coordinates (x,y). How can i use said translation and rotation matrix to find the corresponding (x,y) coordinates in the projection ?

Comment: What exact behaviour should be achieved? Can you specify how would you like to use both?

Comment: That if an interface is projected onto a surface that a user is able to interact with said interface. Therefor the location of the hand should be known (The coordinates of the hands will be in depth coordinates or real world coordinates this is gathered with the kinect). But to give feedback in the projection , the position of the hand has to be known in the projection coordinates. This way if the user touches the projection at for example (220,210) in the camera image. Something can be displayed on the projection at (x,y). Hope this clarifies the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Basically POSIT algorithm estimates the position of the object relative to camera from at least four non planar corresponding points. In the other hand the projector can be seen as a camera so if you identify the known points of the real object on the projected image, known the projection focal length, it should be possible to compute the relative position.

So what you should do is something like:

1. Identify at least four points on some object placed in front of projector. You can calculate the points coordinates using kinect.
2. Then you should identify those points on the projected image in the image coordinate system in the same order as 3d points.
3. Than you can use cvPosit function from OpenCV which will calculate the pose of the object relative to the camera.
4. Than given some object in the 3d space that you measure with kinect you can calculate the image coordinates applying the transformation computed by cvPOSIT.

There can be some specific conditions to be satisfied by the points used by algorithm, so
please see the following for deeper explanation of POSIT:
http://www.cfar.umd.edu/~daniel/daniel_papersfordownload/Pose25Lines.pdf

The following is the link to the opencv posit related documentation:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#posit

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#createpositobject

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#releasepositobject

Step 4 clarification:

Quote from the original POSIT paper:
"The POSIT algorithm finds the translation vector and the transformation matrix that transform the object onto the camera coordinate system so that its feature points fall on the lines
of sight of the image points"

Assume we have n 3d points (kPoints) in the Kinect coordinate system, we have the Rotation (r[3][3]) and Translation (t[3]) from POSIT, focal length of the projector image plane and finally we know the coordinates of the first 3D point (kOrigin) we used with POSIT.
Then we need to translate our points to be in the POSIT coordinate system:

```
kPoints[i] = kPoints[i] - kOrigin;
kPoints[i] = Rotate(kPoints[i], r);
kPoints[i] = kPoints[i] + t;
imagePoint[i].x = focalLength * kPoints[i].x/kPoints[i].z
imagePoint[i].y = focalLength * kPoints[i].y/kPoints[i].z
```

Comment: Hi, What I've currently done is: Project 4 points onto a surface (These coordinates are known). Then I identify the coordinates with the kinect. With those 8 coordinates i execute the POSIT algorithm. This gives me a Translation vector and rotation matrix. I assume that these describe the position of the projector relative to the camera ? And from this point on . What can I do with that rotation matrix and translation vector ? Are these the transform you are talking about ? Or am i missing a step ?

Comment: Yes the rotation and translation that you get is this transformation. Suppose you have some point in 3D coordinates, then you should be able to apply inverse transformation(rotation and translation) to get the coordinates of this point in the camera based coordinate system, then you can project it on your image plane to get the image coordinates. Please note that points provided to the POSIT algorithm is in the coordinate system with origin at the first point so you have somehow translate the kinect coordinates.

Comment: By the way this is another interesting approach -http://augmentedengineering.com/ProCamCalibration/brjones2rsodhi2Final.pdf

Comment: The 3D point is in the camera coordinates (as it is from the kinect). Do you mean that if I apply to inverse transformation on this that i will get the coordinate in the projection ? And what do you mean by "the first point", does this mean that the first calibration point should be in the origin ?

Comment: I followed that posit tutorial but i stopped at the opengl part, because it didn't seem usefull in my case and quit confusing

Comment: I will updte my answer with explanation

Comment: The resulting transform must be applied directly on the 3d points rotation and then translation. I was wrong about inverse transformation, see updated answer.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try to implement this in 10 days (traveling )